# network interfaces not recognized

Tags: networking, configuration, netplan

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 from DVD to an HP computer.  I configured a .yaml file in /etc/netplan to assign static addresses to the two interfaces.  On one interface, the green light is on, and the peer machine reports that the interface is up, and carrier is present.  The other interface currently has nothing connected to it.
However, "ip addr show" reports that both interfaces are down.
How can I debug this, to determine what is causing the network card(s) to be unrecognized?